# javascript в jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp

Есть у меня JSP страница, на которой есть таблица:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col"><spring:message code="queue.id"/></th>
        <th scope="col"><spring:message code="queue.name"/></th>
        <th scope="col" colspan="2"><spring:message code="queue.actions"/></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <c:forEach items="${queues}" var="queue">
        <jsp:useBean id="queue" scope="page" type="ru.myproject.pojo.Queue"/>
        <tr>
            <td>${queue.id}</td>
            <td>${queue.queueName}</td>
            <td><a href="settings/queue/update?id=${user.id}&queueId=${queue.id}"><spring:message code="queue.update"/></a></td>
            <td><a href="settings/queue/delete?id=${user.id}&queueId=${queue.id}"><spring:message code="queue.delete"/></a></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Как сделать, чтоб при нажатии на ссылку UPDATE, ячейки становились редактируемым?

Как вариант нашел вот [тут](http://dayte2.com/editable-table) пример javascript, который при клике на ячейке, делает ее редактируемой. Но я с js только начинаю работать и не могу понять как связать между собой js  и мою таблицу...

Answer (score 0):

```js
function convertTextToInput(el) {
  var inp = document.createElement("input");
  inp.value = el.textContent;
  el.textContent = "";
  el.appendChild(inp);
}

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.querySelectorAll("#test a").forEach(
    i => i.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var tr = this.closest("tr");
      convertTextToInput(tr.cells[0]);
      convertTextToInput(tr.cells[1]);
    }));
});
```

```css
td {
  color: darkgray;
  width: 100px;
}
td input {
  width: 100%;
  border:none;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" id="test">
  <tr>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td>bbb</td>
    <td><a href="#">Edit</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ccc</td>
    <td>ddd</td>
    <td><a href="#">Edit</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```